# Django image. Not correct url

Tags: django

I have image files from:

```
imgage = models.ImageField(upload_to="site_media/media")
```

but if I display this photos in template url to photo is:

```
bad url =  http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/site_media/media/django__white_and_green__by_aruseni-d59g56q.png

correct url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/media/django__white_and_green__by_aruseni-d59g56q.png
```

How to remove 'photo' from this url?

```
<img src="{{ p.img.url }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `/` in front of what you have for `MEDIA_URL` in settings.py.